# Склеить 2 запроса

Tags: sql, php, mysql

Не могу склеить эти 2 запроса

```
SELECT q.*
FROM `subscribers` AS sub, `questions` AS q
WHERE (sub.id = 1 AND q.to = sub.id_subscriber)
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT 20

SELECT d.*
FROM `subscribers` AS sub, `discussion` AS d
WHERE (sub.id = 1 AND d.to = sub.id_subscriber)
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Делаю так

```
(
  SELECT q.`id`, q.`text`, q.`reply`, q.`time`, q.`from`, q.`to`, q.`ip`, q.`is_anonum`, 'null' AS q.`question_id`
  FROM `subscribers` AS sub, `questions` AS q
  WHERE (sub.id = 1 AND q.to = sub.id_subscriber)
  ORDER BY `time` DESC
  LIMIT 20
)UNION (
  SELECT d.`id`, d.`text`, d.`reply`, d.`time`, d.`from`, d.`to`, d.`ip`, d.`is_anonum`, 'null' AS d.`likes`, 'null' AS d.`discussion`, 'null' AS d.`salt`
  FROM `subscribers` AS sub, `discussion` AS d
  WHERE (sub.id = 1 AND d.to = sub.id_subscriber)
  ORDER BY `time` DESC
  LIMIT 20
)
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

Но меня посылают куда по дальше, вот дамп если что

```
CREATE TABLE `discussion` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `text` TEXT NOT NULL, -- Вопрос
  `reply` TEXT NOT NULL, 
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `to` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `ip`  varchar(25) NOT NULL default '', 
  `is_anonum` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  `text` TEXT NOT NULL, 
  `reply` TEXT NOT NULL, 
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `likes` int(8) NOT NULL default '0',
  `discussion` int(8) NOT NULL default '0',
  `salt` char(3) NOT NULL default '', 
  `from` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `to` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `ip`  varchar(25) NOT NULL default '', 
  `is_anonum` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

CREATE TABLE `subscribers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL, -- id юзера
  `id_subscriber` int(11) NOT NULL, -- На кого подписан юзер
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Comment: А какие столбцы д.б. в результате запроса? Общие id, text, reply, time, from, to, ip, is_anonum. Если нужны еще другие, то в одном запросе надо выдавать константу в результат (типа `0 as likes`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Но меня посылают куда по дальше

Вам наверняка показывается сообщение об ошибке. Ваше высказывание абсолютно не информативно.

Попробую помочь.

Запись вот такого рода:

> 'null' AS q.`question_id`

неверна и приводит к ошибке. Вероятнее всего, вы перепутали значения местами
и на самом деле хотели написать вот так (забыв подключить таблицу в условии выборки):

```
q.`question_id` AS 'null'
```

Но даже если исправить все ошибки такого рода, у вас есть еще одна:

*Использовать **[UNION](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28SQL%29)** можно только тогда, когда

**все запросы возвращают одинаковое количество столбцов,

которые содержат совместимые типы данных**.*

У вас же в первом запросе возвращается на два столбца меньше.

Исправьте эти ошибки и запрос заработает.

Comment: В комментарий все не влезает, так что я чуть обрезал. Вроде понял свою ошибку, исправил, теперь пишет "Unknown column 'q.question_id' in 'field list'"

    (
      SELECT q.`id`, q.`text`, q.`reply`, q.`time`, q.`from`, q.`to`, q.`ip`, q.`is_anonum`, q.`question_id` AS 'null', q.`likes`, q.`discussion`, q.`salt`
     ...
    )UNION (
      SELECT d.`id`, d.`text`, d.`reply`, d.`time`, d.`from`, d.`to`, d.`ip`, d.`is_anonum`, d.`question_id`, d.`likes` AS 'null', d.`discussion` AS 'null', d.`salt` AS 'null'
      ...
    )
    ORDER BY `time` DESC

Comment: В вашей таблице `questions` нет поля `question_id`.

Comment: **question_id** у вас в таблице **discussion**, а не **question**  
Таблица **discussion** у вас не подключена ни в блоке **FROM**, ни в условии **WHERE**

Не забудьте дописать условие:  

    q.`id` = `discussion`.`question_id`

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо)

Но вот меня один вопрос беспокоит, к таблице **subscribers** выполняется два однотипных запроса, их можно как-то сократить до одного?

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы "склеить" два запроса оператором `UNION` нужно, чтобы количество столбцов в обоих запросах было одинаковым. Также должны совпадать типы столбцов.

Comment: и нельзя делать order by time desc. если сильно надо пересортировать - нужно обернуть в еще один select

Comment: Почему нельзя? И как обернуть?